# In TypeScript, What is the type of Image?

Tags: typescript, image, interface

I'm declaring an interface which will contains image also. What type do i need to give to it.

```
export interface AdInterface {
    email: string;
    mobile: number;
    image?:   ??
}
```

Comment: How do you represent the image? Is it an URL to an image? Is it blob data? Is it a HTML `<img>` element?

Comment: It's a some kind of file upload image.

Comment: So you grab an image from a file input?

Comment: yes. I will grab from file input

Answer (score 138, accepted):

If your image property contains ...

**Image used as** `<img>` **element**

```
image?: HTMLImageElement
```

---

**URL to image.**

```
image?: String
```

---

**Image as file from** `<input>` **element**

```
image?: File
```

---

Comment: It's recommended to use "string" as type and not "String" for this usage.

Comment: If the image is a byte array, would you recommend using HTMLImageElement or File?

Comment: Type of byte array is `array`. If you need work with `HTMLImageElement` or `File` instead then you need to convert your byte array by conversion specific procedure depending on your needs. Conversions are usualy done by converting to base64 string. More details and examples are at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20756042/how-to-display-an-image-stored-as-byte-array-in-html-javascript and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35038884/download-file-from-bytes-in-javascript

Answer (score 2):

Most image when imported into server-side TypeScript are strings.

For example trying to reference `File` or `HTMLImageElement` on an imported image you will get this error:

> TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'HTMLImageElement'.

I recommend just using string. If you are having an import error for PNG images in TypeScript then take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51100401/typescript-image-import).