# Typescript image import

Tags: reactjs, typescript, module, tsconfig, react-tsx

I found a solution here: [Webpack & Typescript image import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43638454/webpack-typescript-image-import?rq=1)

But i am getting error for this:

```
[ts]
Types of property 'src' are incompatible.
  Type 'typeof import("*.png")' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.
    Type 'typeof import("*.png")' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

I guess i need to cast import somehow, but cant figure out how. 
I am doing this in React. I saw that `src` attribute is defined as `string | undefined`, that is why error is popping.

Here is code:

```
import * as Logo from 'assets/images/logo.png';
```

HTML:

```
<img src={Logo} alt="" />
```

And definition based on above mentioned solution:

```
declare module "*.png" {
  const value: string;
  export default value;
}
```

Tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "jsx": "react",
    "lib": ["es5", "es6", "dom"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "custom_typings"
    ]
  },
  "include": ["./src/**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": ["dist", "build", "node_modules"]
}
```

Comment: According to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36148639/webpack-not-able-to-import-images-using-express-and-angular2-in-typescript/36151803#36151803) you should use require instead of import.

So it should look like this:

`const Logo = require('assets/images/logo.png')`

Comment: Yep i saw that. But that is not elegant way of doing this. The thing is that when you do `import` it works when you load app. But you get lint error.

Comment: `import` works so it should be used. @MarioPetrovic a default import has no name. That is why you can leave out the `* as` part. `import Logo from './logo.jpg'` is fine because it's equivalent to `const Logo = require(./logo.jpg)`

Comment: `<img src={require('assets/images/logo.png')} />` works. What makes it not elegant, if you only need to reference it in that one line? To me, it feels more elegant and bulletproof than modifying `d.ts` files.

Comment: Well it is probably more of a judgement call. But if you setup it with `d.ts` and use it later in your project it makes it more organic and consistent with regular importing.

Answer (score 179, accepted):

One of the ways to get rid of that error is by modifying d.ts file as follows:

```
declare module "*.png"
```

remove

```
{
  const value: string;
  export default value;
}
```

or alternatively you can do:

```
declare module "*.png" {
  const value: any;
  export default value;
}
```

**Update**

The best solution with type-checking is:

```
declare module "*.png" {
   const value: any;
   export = value;
}
```

Comment: Already tried to modify from `string` to `any` and it wont help. It seems that const value is not getting considered when resolving type of imported. As for removing block, it wont work either.

Comment: You can also try this:
declare module '*.png' {
  const value: string;
  export = value;
}

Comment: Hey. Just tried it with `export = value` and it worked. It also gives `string` as type for imported `Logo`. Also, sorry, but your solution to exclude block of code actually worked, so only `declare module "*.png"` worked but didn't give type. So please modify your answer to include solution with `export = value` as best option because of type checking. Thanks very much.

Comment: I want to import svg, png, jpg, jpeg, ... so I have to copy paste declare module or could we define something like regular expression

Comment: I get: TS1192: Module '"*.png"' has no default export.

Comment: @danielrvt you were probably not doing it on `d.ts` / `custom.d.ts`, but somewhere else...

Comment: I added the last solution to my `custom.d.ts`, and it fixed my tslint error, thank you!

Comment: downvoted this answer.  This does not work `Parsing error: Only declares and type imports are allowed inside declare module`.  I tried declare module `"*.png" {
   const value: any;
   export = value;
}`

and also tried `declare module '*.png' { const value: string; export = value; }` and it's complaining about const

Comment: I had trouble getting this to work due to [this long-standing issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28097).  As soon as I moved my wildcard `declare module` statements into their own typings file, rather than an existing `globals.d.ts` I had for other stuff (which happened to `import` an interface declaration...), I was able to `import LOGO from "./logo.png"`.

Comment: The `.d.ts` file needs to be put into the `src/` folder to be working, in case anybody else encounters that problem putting it in the project root.

Comment: I'm annoyed to say my issue is just with IntelliJ IDE just underlining the import. It compiles just fine and even using `// @ts-ignore` suppresses the red underline error. I've tried everything to gain the smart resolution for my IDE; changing syntax was really a last resort `const logo = require("*.png");` which was successful in both compilation and now on my editor.

Comment: I get the following error when declaring image imports as a string: `'string' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.ts(2693)`

Comment: For me the only solution is to ignore the error with `// @ts-ignore`. I can't fathom why such a basic function as loading an image is not working in parcel ?

Comment: @PiyushZalani in your answer, can you describe why the "best solution" in the Update section is better than the original solution?

Comment: Saying that you get type checking with setting something to `any` is just wrong. `any` overrides ALL type checking for that value. It should be avoided whenever possible.

Answer (score 41):

For `react-native`

create `global.d.ts` file on project `root` folder and just add next lines there

```
declare module '*.png' {
  const value: import('react-native').ImageSourcePropType;
  export default value;
}
```

Comment: That's a nice solution, you can also change the value type as your need.

Comment: This works well, but I wish TypeScript checked that files exist when importing them. As-is, it allows me to import a non-existent file, which would result in a runtime error. I've been searching for a way to preserve file existence checks like we get from importing JS/TS but haven't found a way yet.

Comment: for react-native I've just created a types.d.ts in the root with the simplest answer and worked like a charm:
`declare module "*.png"

Comment: @FacundoColombier sure. It is just the same, but with type.
And what type did you get in code? It will solve problem with file absence? :)

Answer (score 5):

I created the index.d.ts and added 'declare module "*.jpg"' it didn't work but when I changed the name to custom.d.ts (or any other name) it worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, even with the global.d.ts configured, it wasn't  working due to the import. instead of

> import * as Logo from 'assets/images/logo.png';

i used:

> import image from 'assets/images/logo.png';

it worked fine.