# Import images in a js project managed with jsconfig.conf and webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, visual-studio-code

I'm finding it difficult to configure a JS project managed with a `/jsconfig.json` file and webpack, where I'm importing two images in its main js script. Although I tried to follow [this link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig#_using-webpack-aliases), I still get the following error:

`Cannot find module 'images/right.png' or its corresponding type declarations.`

in my main script at this line (import of packages located inside node_modules work well):

```js
    import image from 'images/right.png';
```

My `/jsconfig/json` looks like this:

```
    {
      "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "checkJs": true,
        "baseUrl": "src",
        "paths": {
          "images/*": ["./images/*"]
        }
      },
      "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist"],
      "include": ["src"]
    }
```

and my project structure:

```
    dist
    src
      app.js
      images.js
    jsconfig.json
    webpack.config.js
```

The relevant part in my `webpack.config.js` is:

```js
    module.exports = {
      resolve: {
        // instead of relative path in import
        alias: {
          images: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/images'),
        },
      },
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently js projects are unable to load files other than js/ts scripts (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51163365/2228912)). As a result a module needs to be declared in `src/images.d.ts`:

```js
declare module "*.png" {
  const value: string;
  export default value;
}
```