# Cannot find module... while importing images

Tags: reactjs, import

Maybe someone know how to fix this? I tried to create index.d.ts file and add

```js
declare module '*.png'
```

inside but nothing helped

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript image import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51100401/typescript-image-import)

Comment: This might be entirely about you path. Are you able to share a screenshot that shows your file path? (Basically, how your files are arranged - interest in this is the path to `images`)

Comment: @MwamiTovi I don't think that there is a problem in file path. I tried to use const articleLogo = require("./images/articleLogo.png") and it works correct. But i need to use import

Comment: WIth `import`, try capitalizing the entire thing e.g. `import ArticleLogo from...` and see what happens