# Can not import png in a Vue app in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, import, png

Made the app with `vue ui`, Vue v2 + TypeScript.

For some component I need to import .png file.

In TypeScript part I'm trying to import:

```
import i7 from '@/assets/nimg/7.png';
```

or

```
import * as i7 from '@/assets/nimg/7.png';
```

Add imported as a `data` to component, and then put it to template:

```
<img src={i7} alt="" />
```

Well, I have in terminal:

> Cannot find module '@/assets/nimg/7.png' or its corresponding type declarations.

File is there, so I think the problem is in type.

Is this means a need to fix some rules in `tsconfig.json`, or `babel.config.js`?

And if yes, what changes I need to put there?

Comment: I believe this should help https://stackoverflow.com/a/51163365/3388225