# How to fix TypeScript error for static import images in nextjs

Tags: typescript, next.js, nextjs-image

I am trying to optimize images in my nextjs app, but for some reason, I am facing an issue that says: Cannot find module '/images/homeBg.jpg' or its corresponding type declarations.

The image is stored in public/images/name.jpg.

```
import { Layout } from '@common';
import Trips from '@ui/Trips/Trips';
import Image from 'next/image';
import bgImage from '/images/homeBg.jpg';
const HomePage = () => {
  return (
    <div className="relative h-screen w-full">
      <Image
        src={bgImage}
        fill
        className="-z-10 object-cover"
        alt="backgound_image_for_home_page"
      />
      <div className="mx-auto flex h-full w-full max-w-[2000px] flex-col space-y-10 px-7 py-36 lg:px-14">
        <h3 className="text-3xl font-normal leading-10 tracking-wider text-white lg:text-4xl">
          Welcome back, <br /> <span className="font-bold">Nedim!</span>
        </h3>
        <Trips />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default HomePage;

HomePage.layout = Layout;
```

Comment: Pretty sure the answers here still apply: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51100401/typescript-image-import

Comment: @vera. Yea, I did it, but still facing this problem

Comment: An import like this should be relative and not absolute. https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/image-optimization#local-images

Answer (score 4):

When you are starting your Next.JS app in dev mode it will create `next-env.d.ts` in the root of your project as well as some type-definition files in `.next/types` folder that is necessary for type safety.

Run the development command `npm run dev` at least once to see the changes.

You can also explicitly import `next-env.d.ts` in your tsconfig file

```json
{
  "include": [
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx",
    "next-env.d.ts",
    ".next/types/**/*.ts"
  ],
  ...  
}
```