# Angular 2 Change bytea to download pdf

Tags: angular, blob

How to convert bytea to pdf downloadable file?
currently i can get the bytea data. But i dint know how to convert to pdf type. I keep searching the internet but could not found it. Thanks in advance

In component:

```
downloadFile(instanceId){
  this.filestorageService.loadByInstance(instanceId).subscribe(
    obj => {

      console.log(obj)
      var data = obj.content;
      var blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/pdf' });
      var url= window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      window.open(url);
    }
  );
}
```

In html:

```
<a href="#" (click)="downloadFile(instanceId)" >download file</a>
```

Comment: i found the solution on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35038884/download-file-from-bytes-in-javascript