# How to get binary data of .ogg file from string file path

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ogg

In JavaScript, how would I go about going from having a string file path pointing to a .ogg file to getting the file's binary content?

I am using Vue's input element to get the file path from the user.

Comment: The question doesn't make sense in general. It's unknown how .ogg is related to the app.  File path to which location? Is it served by web server or something else?

Comment: @EstusFlask I don't see why it matters how they're related. I have a path to a .ogg file and I want to get its binary contents. It's client side.

Comment: What does this path look like? Is it path to user's local file or what? Where does it come from? The details matter, unless you know enough about the solution enough to provide it for your own question. The question lacks clear problem statement. Please, explain your case in details.

Comment: @EstusFlask The file path comes from the Vue.js input element. The user browses for a .ogg file on their system, selects it, then submits it. A callback function is associated with the submission of the file, which gets the user-selected file path from the event object passed in. Inside that callback function is where I want to convert the file path to the binary counterpart. The selected file has the file path "C:\fakepath\<file>". The whole thing is a part of a web server on the client side.

Comment: In this case you likely need FileReader, something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62454632/create-file-from-filereader-readasarraybuffer , or file arrayBuffer https://stackoverflow.com/a/67220791/3731501

Comment: @EstusFlask I've looked at both of those, but the main intermediate issue I'm having is getting the string file path into a blob form with the file binary data (I think). I very rarely use JS or Vue, so sorry if I sound very ignorant here.

Comment: You can't get the contents from random file path by means of client-side app, it would be a huge security hole. It needs specifically a path that's held by File object that a user chose in file input, which seems to be your case and that's what the links show. If your case differs and a user runs local web server or something then this could be done on server side.