# Create pdf in memory or launch Byte[] as pdf to browser

Tags: c#, .net

Im currently working in a rather old system where we have already implemented functions for getting the filepath to a pdf which we launch to view in a browser. My current task is to implement functionality for us to also launch a pdf in our new storage (azure blob) which i will recieve as a `Byte[]`. I have a functioning version where i create a temporary pdf which i launch the same way as the older implementation and storage, but it is preferable if i could implement functionality where i do not have to create a physical copy of the pdf.

I have not gotten this to work sadly, does anyone have any idea if it is possible to save a pdf in memory without creating a physicla pdf file, or directly launch a `byte[]` as a pdf to the browser?

I would love for it to work similar to this where i have a local pdf document, but without creating the document itself.

```cs
string app = @"C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe";

string temp = "pdf as base64";

byte\[\] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(temp);

System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("newTest.pdf", bytes);

string path = Path.GetFullPath("newTest.pdf");

// whatever condition to launch
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(app, path);
```

Comment: With Chrome, navigating to "data:application/pdf;base64, BASE64_ENCODED_PDF_DATA" might work.

Comment: I assume you mean "creating a local file" or "copy the file to the local file system". I would interpret "physical copy of the pdf" to mean printing the file to paper.

Comment: what is your back-side? Is this web api, asp.net or what? If this was some browser app that downloads bytes from Web Api then saves it locally and opens it - this is possible. Or something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35038884/download-file-from-bytes-in-javascript

Comment: To clarify what i meant with physical copy => Local file. I did not want to create a pdf file that was stored anywhere.

Comment: Now got a request to open it in adobe acrobat instead, which means that i most likely will have to create a temporary pdf anyways...